# awseducate - How to add security to the AWS services used on my Flask web page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

For a project I'm working on, I am currently using S3 to hold photos and DynamoDB to hold data and a link to the photo in S3. The AWS account is an awseducate account. I've created a page using the Flask framework to view this data (it scans the table on DynamoDB and downloads the photo from S3) as a table.

I wanted to add some security to my methods of reading from DynamoDB and S3 on my web page because I've just pasted my admin credentials in the app.py to access the DB and made the photos on S3 public. I wanted to create a User with a restricted role with policies to only read from the DB, but I found out with my AWSEducate account, I can't create access keys so I'm not sure how to implement the user.

How could I implement a level of security on my web page?

Restrictions of AWSEducate IAM:
IAM: You can create users, but cannot attach a login profile. You are not permitted to use SAML or third party providers with IAM. You cannot create access keys for additional users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I implement a level of security on my web page?

You would use an [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) with permissions to access your database, and attach it to your instance. This is **good practice**.

In contrast, hard coding your IAM user credentials in your app is **bad practice** and should not be used. Use instance role instead in your case.

Comment: For instance roles, I need to have an EC2 Instance running, right? I'm currently running my code just on my local computer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I created the instance role and it worked wonders :)

Comment: @LockandLoll No problem. Glad it worked out.